# Closure returns its reference/pointer instead of return value

Tags: grails, groovy

When I output a property, I think I get the reference/pointer of the closure instead of the expected return value.

For instance, for the following property: `${g.goalsAgainstAverage}`:

```
<td header="stathdr5 stathdr${g.leagueId} stathdrgt${g.leagueId}_${g.gameTypeId}">${g.goalsAgainstAverage}</td>
```

Will output:

```
<td header="stathdr5 stathdr1 stathdrgt1_3">com.mgs.StatService$__tt__getSeasonStats_closure10$_closure24$_closure25@61df269d</td>
```

Here is the service generating the value (see `calcGoalsAgainstAverage`):

```
import grails.transaction.Transactional

@Transactional
class StatService {

    def serviceMethod() {

    }

    def getSeasonStats(Long userId, Long seasonId){

        def seasonRaw = Game.createCriteria().list{
            ...
        }

        def seasonStats = seasonRaw
        .groupBy { it.leagueId }
        .collect { leagueId, records -> 
            [
                ...
                gameTypes: records.collect { 
                    [
                        ...
                        goalsAgainstAverage: {calcGoalsAgainstAverage(it.secondsPlayed, it.minutesPlayed, it.gameInMinutes, it.goalsAgainst)}
                    ] 
                }
            ]
        }
        return seasonStats
    }

    double calcGoalsAgainstAverage(int secondsPlayed, int minutesPlayed, int gameInMinutes, int goalsAgainst){
        ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're returning a closure...

Either change:

```
goalsAgainstAverage: {calcGoalsAgainstAverage(it.secondsPlayed, it.minutesPlayed, it.gameInMinutes, it.goalsAgainst)}
```

To

```
goalsAgainstAverage: calcGoalsAgainstAverage(it.secondsPlayed, it.minutesPlayed, it.gameInMinutes, it.goalsAgainst)
```

Or, change

```
${g.goalsAgainstAverage}
```

To

```
${g.goalsAgainstAverage()}
```

Comment: I'm an idiot. I had your first suggestion implemented but I was getting an error related to a casting issue between the expected parameters and what was passed. If I would have read that error message properly, I would have seen that yesterday and saved myself some grief.